Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(browser). angular 17
I'm creating a new application project in single-spa using angular 17, when I try to run the project, I get this message:
Error: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" must NOT have additional properties(browser).
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1


In recent angular versions browser was renamed to main

This message is because in angular.json there is an invalid property: browser, remove that line. Probably the line 22.
angular.json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "browser": "src/main.ts",

